# Smooth Line Graph in Android with Custom Formating

Tags: android

I want to draw smooth line graph in Android with custom formatting like...

-- Grid Line when tap on graph.

-- Custom X and Y axis title and data.

-- For single curve, different color for different values

Comment: I am not able to customized formatting.

Comment: I also want  for single curve different color for different values. like nike app

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options to draw graph on android view.
1. Google charts 
2. aCartEngine charting library
3. Android plot
4. Android GraphView library

Have you tried using any of these? or are you stuck some where?

I have used android graph view in one of my personal project, its fairly simple to use

Step 1: Add a layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" > </LinearLayout>
```

Step 2 Add Graph-View jar file

Step 3 Draw graph from code

```
// initilize graph series data
GraphViewSeries sampleGraph = new GraphViewSeries(new GraphViewData[] {
    new GraphViewData(1, 2.0d)
    , new GraphViewData(2, 1.5d)
    , new GraphViewData(3, 2.5d)
    , new GraphViewData(4, 1.0d)
});
GraphView graphView = new LineGraphView(
    this // context
    , "Sample Graph" // heading
);
graphView.addSeries(sampleGraph);
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.MainLayout);
layout.addView(graphView);
```